# PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase not found Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony4

I'm trying to add a form to a controller and it just returns this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /var/www/site/vendor/symfony/form/Test/FormIntegrationTestCase.php on line 21

Though, I'm not quite sure why. At first glance it would seem that PHPUnit is not found but running `cat composer.json` in my directory says otherwise:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.1",
        "symfony/console": "^4.1",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^4.1",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^4.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/process": "^4.1",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.1",
        "symfony/web-link": "^4.1",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "*",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.1",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.5",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.1",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

so I can see it there.. Here's my controller:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller\Bug;

    use App\Entity\Bug;
    use App\Form\Bug\AddType;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    class AddController extends Controller
    {
        public function add(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
        {
            # I know setting errors this way isn't best
            # but was faced with White Screen of Death
            ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            error_reporting(-1);

            $bug = new Bug();

            $form = $this->createForm(AddType::class, $bug);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            $user = $this->getUser();

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $bug->setCreatedTs(new \DateTime());
                $bug->setSubmittedBy($user);
                $bug->setStatus('new');

                try {
                    $em->persist($bug);
                    $em->flush();

                    $this->addFlash('success', 'Bug Submitted.');

                    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Incoming Bug'))
                        ->setTo('t.taylor@sinnis.co.uk')
                        ->setBody(
                            $this->renderView(
                                'emails/bugs/add.html.twig',
                                array(
                                    'bug' => $bug,
                                    'submitted_by' => $user
                                )
                            ),
                            'text/html'
                        );

                    $mailer->send($message);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->addFlash('danger', 'Processing Error. Please try again.');
                }

                return $this->redirectToRoute('bug_add');
            }

            return $this->render('bug/add.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
        }
    }
```

my FormType:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Form\Bug;

    use App\Entity\Bug;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\Extension\Core\Type\TextTypeTest;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    class AddType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('summary', TextTypeTest::class)
                ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
                ->add('priority', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Low' => 'low',
                        'Medium' => 'medium',
                        'High' => 'high',
                        'Site Breaking' => 'extreme'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('website', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Site One' => 'site-one',
                        'Site Two' => 'site-two',
                        'Site Three' => 'site-three'
                    )
                ));
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array());
        }
    }
```

my twig file is just a basic implementation of the form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I'm not sure why this error is occuring or how to stop it? I'm not trying anthing with PHPUnit, yet here it rears its ugly head..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem here:

```
$builder->add('summary', TextTypeTest::class)
```

you need to change it to

```
$builder->add('summary', TextType::class)
```

So you can delete this use

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\Extension\Core\Type\TextTypeTest;
```

And add this one:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
```

Comment: correct indeed! Damn IDE's and their helpful autocompletes xD ty :)

Comment: Glad to help you @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, would you please explain why this fixes the OP's issue and relationship between the original error message and the fix which apparently worked?